# setBackgroundColor() doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a `RelativeLayout` and a `Button` in my `Activity` 
I want to run a code when I click on the `Button`, so I wrote the following code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/flashlight"
    android:onClick="NightSwitch" />
```

and then I have the following in my `Activity.java`

```
public void NightSwitch(View v){
    String One = "1"; //states day
    String Zero = "0"; //states night

    int color1 = getResources().getColor(R.color.darkblue);
    int color2 = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);

    RelativeLayout rele = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    String state = getString(R.string.night_switch);

    if(state.equals(One)){
        rele.setBackgroundColor(color1);
    }

    if(state.equals(Zero)){
        rele.setBackgroundColor(color2);
    }
}
```

### Everything is ok, but `setBackgroundColor()` does not work and causes a crash. also, how can I debug program in a VB style? Is it even possible?

Logcat :

01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    ... 11 more
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    at com.example.jonathanlseagull.NumOneActivity.NightSwitch(NumOneActivity.java:46)
01-27 17:38:45.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21427):    ... 14 more

onCreate();

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_num_one);
}
```

Comment: What is the id of the RelativeLayout defined in the xml layout ?

Comment: Try `state.equals("One")` and same with other statement. I think inverted commas `"` might work

Comment: Need logcat, the entire xml layout and the definition of the color1 and color2

Comment: Since you say this is causing a crash, posting the stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: Apart from logcat, post onCreate() too...

Answer (score 3):

you should use

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
```

instead of

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color1);  // this method accepts Color not resource.
```

Comment: what is the code NumOneActivity.java:46? you are getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Line 46 : `rele.setBackgroundColor(color2);` do you mean color2 is null ?

Comment: probably rele is getting null check this value with a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a Color (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) attribute instead of the int code

```
if(state.equals(One))
{
    rele.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CB8FB"));
}
else
{
    rele.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```